Why this concurrent code get stuck after giving output for sometime?
So I'm learning concurrency and I'm stuck in an issue. I have explain my code below with the issue I'm facing.


class Task - It is consist of two operand and an operator.
enum TaskType - It contains four types : ADD, SUB, MUL, DIV.
class TaskQueue - This is a queue which stores object of type Task. The capacity is 25.
class TaskGen - This randomly takes two operand b/w 10 to 20 and randomly select operand from TaskType. Pushes it to TaskQueue. If queue is full then it waits.
class TaskExec- This waits until there is any Task inside the queue. It pops the Task object and performs the operation.

Issue - After sometime the output get stuck. If I remove the synchronized from isQueueEmpty method in TaskExec and isQueueFull in TaskGen class, the program runs smoothly.
Main.java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TaskQueue queue = new TaskQueue();
        Object lock = new Object();
        Thread gen = new Thread(new TaskGen(queue, lock));
        Thread exec = new Thread(new TaskExec(queue, lock));

        gen.start();
        exec.start();

        System.out.println("Bye from main...");
    }
}


Task.java

public class Task {
    private final int op1, op2;
    private final TaskType type;

    public Task(int op1, int op2, TaskType type) {
        this.op1 = op1;
        this.op2 = op2;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public int getOp1() {
        return op1;
    }

    public int getOp2() {
        return op2;
    }

    public TaskType getType() {
        return type;
    }
}

TaskType.java

public enum TaskType {
    ADD,
    SUB,
    MUL,
    DIV
}

TaskQueue.java
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Queue;

public class TaskQueue {
    private final Queue<Task> queue;
    private final int SIZE = 25;

    public TaskQueue() {
        this.queue = new ArrayDeque<>(SIZE);
    }

    public synchronized void push(Task t) {
        if (this.queue.size() == SIZE)
            throw new RuntimeException("Queue Overflow...");
        this.queue.add(t);
    }

    public synchronized Task pop() {
        if (this.queue.isEmpty() )
            throw new RuntimeException("Queue Underflow...");
        return this.queue.remove();
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        return this.queue.size() == SIZE;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return this.queue.isEmpty();
    }
}

TaskGen.java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class TaskGen implements Runnable {

    private TaskQueue queue;
    private Object lock;

    public TaskGen(TaskQueue queue, Object lock) {
        this.queue = queue;
        this.lock = lock;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Random r = new Random();
        List<TaskType> types = Arrays.asList(TaskType.ADD, TaskType.SUB, TaskType.MUL, TaskType.DIV);
        while (true) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                while (this.isQueueFull()) {
                    try {
                        lock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
                Task t = new Task(
                        r.nextInt(10,20),
                        r.nextInt(10, 20),
                        types.get(r.nextInt(0, 4)
                        )
                );
                System.out.println("Added task : " + t.getType() + " " + t.getOp1() + " " + t.getOp2());
                this.queue.push(t);
                lock.notify();
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isQueueFull() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            System.out.println("is queue Full : " + this.queue.isFull());
            return this.queue.isFull();
        }
    }
}

TaskExec.java

public class TaskExec implements Runnable {

    private TaskQueue queue;
    private Object lock;

    public TaskExec(TaskQueue queue, Object lock) {
        this.queue = queue;
        this.lock = lock;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            while (this.isQueueEmpty()) {
                try {
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        lock.wait();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
            synchronized (lock) {
                Task t = this.queue.pop();
                lock.notify();
                int res = 0;
                if (t.getType().equals(TaskType.ADD)) {
                    res = t.getOp1() + t.getOp2();
                } else if (t.getType().equals(TaskType.SUB)) {
                    res = t.getOp1() - t.getOp2();
                } else if (t.getType().equals(TaskType.MUL)) {
                    res = t.getOp1() * t.getOp2();
                } else if (t.getType().equals(TaskType.DIV)) {
                    res = t.getOp1() / t.getOp2();
                }

                System.out.println("Result : " + res);
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isQueueEmpty() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            System.out.println("is queue empty : " + this.queue.isEmpty());
            return this.queue.isEmpty();
        }
    }
}

I know the program can be simplified by using only one synchronized in each class, but I want to figure out why this solution is not working out.

What does a thread dump show?

@tgdavies here -> https://pastebin.com/a30VnxAt

Hint: synchronize the whole content of the while (true) loop in TaskExec, as done in TaskGen (one synchronize to rule them all) Hint2: prefer classes from the java.util.concurrent package

@user85421 Thanks, but I would like to know what is the issue with the above program.

my guess, in short: notify() will only wke up a process that is waiting - while the queue is being filled, TaskGen is holding the lock, so TaskExec cannot call wait(), unless already waiting, so TaskGen calling notify does nothing. Once the queue is full, after calling notify(), the lock is release by TaskGen; now TaskExec can enter the synchronized block and call wait()... but no one is calling notify()

maybe it is helpful to add some output or logging like System.out.println("Exec sync"); synchronized (lock) { System.out.println("Exec wait"); lock.wait(); (also a smaller queue for less output)

@user85421 here's the program output -> https://pastebin.com/i4BZWZJF

Sorry, you don't have permission to visit this site. || Website blocked || Not allowed to browse FileHost category (but I did not get time to analyze it anyway :-/ - consider rzwitserloot's answer)

There are multiple bugs in this code.
Deadlock risk
This is a deadlock:
Thread A's code flow:
synchronized (lock1) {
  // possibly lots of other stuff
  synchronized (lock2) {
    // actions
  }
}

Thread B's:
synchronized (lock2) {
  // possibly lots of other stuff
  synchronized (lock1) {
    // actions
  }
}

Where, of course, those 2 nested synchronized constructs don't actually have to be present in a single method, it's the same situation if a method locks on lock1 then calls a method that ends up locking on lock2.
The easy solution to avoid deadlocks is to only ever use a single lock. You can't deadlock if you're synchronizing on only one thing.
Your code synchronizes on lock in TaskExec and TaskGen which end up using the same object (because your main code makes one lock object and passes it to both), but synchronizes on the TaskQueue instance as well (because that class has public synchronized methods which is shorthand for wrapping the entire method body in synchronized (this) {} - and that this is obviously not the same object as what lock is pointing to.
That's two locks. You're probably avoiding actual deadlocks because the code tends to establish lock first, then call one of the synchronized methods in TaskQueue second (and never the other way around), but the behaviour you observe strongly suggests it is a dead lock situation after all.
Regardless of whether its deadlocking or not, this situation is just bad. You should not have 2 locks here. You're over-applying locks and under-applying locks because your code haphazardly applies locking: Every time you feel it is needed you toss a synchronized in there as if it's a magic spell. Define clearly which code is responsible for what and lock accordingly. Generally, you want the utilities not to acquire locks. TaskQueue is a utility used by TaskGen/TaskExec, so, TaskQueue shouldn't lock at all.
Incorrect usage of locking
Take this code:

while (this.isQueueEmpty()) {
  try {
    synchronized (lock) {
      lock.wait();
    }


This is wrong. Your isQueueEmpty() method itself also locks on lock. So, the code flow goes like this:

Acquire lock lock.
Check if the queue is empty. Let's say it is empty.
Release lock lock.
Let's say that some other thread now adds an item to the queue. It can; the lock is free!
Acquire lock lock. Which will take some time; some other thread is busy adding stuff to the queue.
Lock is now acquired. wait on lock (which will release the lock for as long as we are waiting). We shall be waiting forever - because there is stuff in the queue so we should be clearing that out of there, but we're waiting anyway.

Any information you glean about the state of the system is useless once you relinquish a lock. After all, another thread can now change all that state. You can no longer make any decisions based on what you observed. So, you can't determine: "Oh, the queue is empty, therefore I shall wait" where you call lock.wait(). Because you have no idea that the queue is empty. "But, I called .isQueueEmpty()!" - sure, you did, and the answer that it provided is irrelevant. Because you released that lock.
Remember, wait() releases a lock for the duration of waiting. You did it right in the queue filling code (you acquire the lock, then you check if the queue has room and act accordingly). The same thing needs to be applied to your queue emptying code.
Some unfortunate style choices
Your if (t.getType().equals(TaskType.ADD)) { block should optimally end in } else throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected type: " + t.getType());. Generally whenever your code has the property that if an unexpected/impossible-in-the-eyes-of-the-programmer situation occurs, that it silently does weird things (in this case, silently do nothing), that's bad. The best thing to do when the system is in a state you do not understand (and, all impossible situations are by definition un-understood - if the code is in a state you deem not possible, it is by definition in an un-understood state), is to throw.

Thanks for your answer. I finally understand what is issue.
